# event.keycode is not working tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, keycode

Here I am just designing simple wandrer game, and I would like to use <kbd>Esc</kbd> button to exit game and use <kbd>Space</kbd> button to attack. I have used mac Keycode of each in my code but it is not working. Here is my main.py:

```
 m = Utils.matrix
 def on_key_press(event):
    #exit
    if event.keycode == 53:
     print(event.keycode)
     root.destroy()

    #battle
    opponent = False
    for char in game.get_characters():
        if event.keycode == 49 and coords(hero) == coords(char):
            opponent = hero.battle(char)
    if opponent:
        game.remove_character(opponent)
    #initialise new game object and level up characters
    if game.get_char_length() < 1:
        new_level()
        game.create_monsters()
        game.level_up_chars(hero.level)
        hero.x = 0
        hero.y = 0
        hero.set_image(hero_down)

    canvas.delete("all")
    stats()
    draw_canvas()


canvas.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)
canvas.pack()
```

Here i just tried to create a separate function and it is still not working, the other similar function such as keyup(), keydown() ... are working perfectly but for "esc" and "space" no.

```
m = Utils.matrix
def coords(char):
    x, y = char.get_coordinates()
    x, y = int(x / 72), int(y / 72)
    return x, y
def leftKey(event):
  if  m[coords(hero)[1]][coords(hero)[0] - 1] != 1 and coords(hero)[0] > 0: #left
     hero.move(x=-72)
     hero.set_image(hero_left)

def rightKey(event):
    if  m[coords(hero)[1]][coords(hero)[0]+1] != 1 and coords(hero)[0]<=9:   #right
     hero.move(x=72)
     hero.set_image(hero_right)

def upKey(event):
    if  m[coords(hero)[1] - 1][coords(hero)[0]] != 1 and coords(hero)[1] > 0:  # up
     hero.move(y=-72)
     hero.set_image(hero_up)

def downKey(event):
    if  m[coords(hero)[1] + 1][coords(hero)[0]] != 1 and coords(hero)[1] <= 9:  # down
     hero.move(y=72)
     hero.set_image(hero_down)

def close(event):
    # canvas.withdraw()  # if you want to bring it back
    # sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing
    root.destry()

root.bind('<Escape>', close)

root.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
root.bind('<Right>', rightKey)
root.bind('<Up>', upKey)
root.bind('<Down>', downKey)
# root.bind("<KeyPress>", close)




enter code here
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working"? Have you tried to e.g. `print(event.keycode)` to see what the actual keycodes are when you press those keys?

Comment: Why don't you bind directly to the escape and space key, and call functions dedicated to each?

Comment: @AKX Yes I have tried but no output

Comment: @RoxanaSlj No output even if you add `print(event.keycode)` where you now have `#exit`? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @AKX I have edited my code , and added print() but there no object printed in console neither debugger , I know it sounds silly. just to mention that I am new to python and pycharm , so i have some lack of debugging skills

Comment: @BryanOakley.                                                                                                               def close(event):
        
        root.destry()

    root.bind('<Escape>', close)

Comment: @BryanOakley is it what you mean?

Comment: @RoxanaSlj If you get no output, that sounds like `on_key_press` is not being called at all...

Comment: @AKX Please check the other approach that I have added